# Global variable does not increment

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

Most of the action is in the function `next`. The other functions are provided for context. The global variable `tally` increments as it should when the right answer is selected. However the variable `nr` is not incremented and I can't figure out way it is not.

You can see that I commented out that the `next` function returned an object with `tally` and `nr` and assigned those values in the event listener. When I did it that way, it worked. But it should work the other way as well, right.

```
var nr = 0;
var tally = 0;

function onLoadEvent(nr) {
    //alert('onload');
    var quiz = document.getElementById('quiz');
    var question = allQuestions[nr];
    var next = quiz.lastElementChild;

    var qHeader = "<h2>" + question.question + "</h2>";
    var q = "";
    for(var i=0;i<question.choices.length;i++){
        q = q + '<p><label for="a' + i + '">' +
            '<input type="radio" id="a' + i + '" name="q" value="' +
            i + '">' + question.choices[i] + '</label></p>';
    }
    quiz.innerHTML = qHeader + q + next.outerHTML;
    //next = document.getElementById('next');
}

function getChecked(){
    var radios = document.getElementsByName('q');
    var radio;
    for(var i=0;i<radios.length;i++){
        if(radios[i].checked){
            radio = radios[i];
            break;
        }
    }
    return radio;
}

function next(nr){
    if (getChecked() !== undefined) {
        var answer = getChecked();
        if(answer.value == allQuestions[nr].correctAnswer){
            tally = tally + 1;
        }
        nr = nr + 1;
        if (nr>=allQuestions.length){
            alert("You got " + tally + " points!");
        } else {
            onLoadEvent(nr);
        }
    } else {
        alert('You need to check a radio button');
    }
    //return {nr: nr, tally: tally};
}

var form = document.getElementById('quiz');
form.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    if(event.target.id === 'next'){
        next(nr);
        //nr = obj.nr;
        //tally = obj.tally;
    } else if(event.target.id === 'prev'){}
}, false);

window.addEventListener('load', function(event){onLoadEvent(nr);}, false);
```

Comment: You are accepting parameters with same name `nr` which is hiding global scope `nr`. Solution to your problem is remove `nr` as parameter. So use `function onLoadEvent()` instead of `function onLoadEvent(nr)`

Comment: Thanks! Add that as an answer and I'll give you credit for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accepting parameters with same name `nr` which is hiding global scope `nr`.

Solution to your problem is remove `nr` as parameter. So use `function onLoadEvent()` instead of `function onLoadEvent(nr)`